# Photoshop script to duplicate and rename layer

Tags: scripting, photoshop, jsx, photoshop-script

While creating a script that would automate all the different tasks I do when I start working on a new picture on Photoshop, I encountered the following problem.

I want to create different groups and different layers inside these groups. Everything goes perfectly fine until this :

```
#target photoshop

app.bringToFront();

var doc = app.activeDocument;

newCurve();

var clippingHelpLayerLight = doc.activeLayer;
clippingHelpLayerLight.blendMode = BlendMode.SCREEN;
clippingHelpLayerLight.name = "Clipping Help Layer - Light";
clippingHelpLayerLight.visible = false;
clippingHelpLayerLight.duplicate();

var clippingHelpLayerLighter = doc.activeLayer;
clippingHelpLayerLighter.name = "Clipping Help Layer - Lighter";
clippingHelpLayerLighter.visible = false;

function newCurve() {
    var c_ADJ_LAYER = charIDToTypeID("AdjL");
    var c_ADJUSTMENT = charIDToTypeID("Adjs");
    var c_CHANNEL = charIDToTypeID("Chnl");
    var c_COMPOSITE = charIDToTypeID("Cmps");
    var c_CURVE = charIDToTypeID("Crv ");
    var c_CURVE_A = charIDToTypeID("CrvA");
    var c_CURVES = charIDToTypeID("Crvs");
    var c_HORIZONTAL = charIDToTypeID("Hrzn");
    var c_MAKE = charIDToTypeID("Mk  ");
    var c_NULL = charIDToTypeID("null");
    var c_POINT = charIDToTypeID("Pnt ");
    var c_TYPE = charIDToTypeID("Type");
    var c_USING = charIDToTypeID("Usng");
    var c_VERTICAL = charIDToTypeID("Vrtc");

    var d_CURVES_LAYER = new ActionDescriptor();
    // Contains all the information necessary to perform the "MAKE" action
    var r_CLASS = new ActionReference();
    r_CLASS.putClass(c_ADJ_LAYER);
    d_CURVES_LAYER.putReference(c_NULL, r_CLASS);
    // Class of make action is of an ajdustment layer
    var d_TYPE_CURVES = new ActionDescriptor();
    // Contains all the information about all the curves
    var d_CHANNEL_CURVES = new ActionDescriptor();
    var l_CHANNEL_CURVES = new ActionList();
    // Contains a list of channel curves
    var d_CHANNEL_CURVE = new ActionDescriptor();
    // Information for 1 channel curve
    var r_CHANNEL = new ActionReference();
    r_CHANNEL.putEnumerated(c_CHANNEL, c_CHANNEL, c_COMPOSITE);
    // This curve is for the composite channel - VARIES
    d_CHANNEL_CURVE.putReference(c_CHANNEL, r_CHANNEL);
    // Contains the point list
    var l_POINTS = new ActionList();
    // List of points for this channel - LENGTH VARIES
    var d_POINT = new ActionDescriptor();
    // One point on the curve, has INPUT and OUTPUT value
    d_POINT.putDouble(c_HORIZONTAL, 0.000000);
    d_POINT.putDouble(c_VERTICAL, 0.000000);
    l_POINTS.putObject(c_POINT, d_POINT);
    //var d_POINT3 = new ActionDescriptor();
    d_POINT.putDouble(c_HORIZONTAL, 255.000000);
    d_POINT.putDouble(c_VERTICAL, 255.000000);
    l_POINTS.putObject(c_POINT, d_POINT);
    // Made the list of points
    d_CHANNEL_CURVE.putList(c_CURVE, l_POINTS);
    // Now have a list of points for a specific channel
    l_CHANNEL_CURVES.putObject(c_CURVE_A, d_CHANNEL_CURVE);
    // Add to the list of channel curves
    d_CHANNEL_CURVES.putList(c_ADJUSTMENT, l_CHANNEL_CURVES);
    // All the channel curves are inside here
    d_TYPE_CURVES.putObject(c_TYPE, c_CURVES, d_CHANNEL_CURVES);
    // .....
    d_CURVES_LAYER.putObject(c_USING, c_ADJ_LAYER, d_TYPE_CURVES);
    // package the curves and definition of the adjustment layer type
    executeAction(c_MAKE, d_CURVES_LAYER, DialogModes.NO);
}
```

I actually want to create a first layer called "Clipping Help Layer - Light", blend mode : screen and turn it off. Then duplicate it, change the name of the new layer as "Clipping Help Layer - Lighter" and turn it off too.

Like this : [Screenshot of what I would like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcwfT.png)

It does create the 2 layers, but the first one has " copy" at the end of its name and it stays turned on.

[Screenshot of the actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsAMT.png)

Why ?

I can't understand why it doesn't work as expected and can't manage to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: I can't see your source image, so this is a stab in the dark,  you might want to use getLayerByname to make the new lighter layer the activeLayer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! It's the first time I ask for help about scripting and I tried to keep it simple by copying here only the useful part for my question.

I now realize I haven't copied enough of the code to make sense...

Comment: So I tried to add this before the second renaming :

    doc.activeLayer = doc.artLayers.getByName("Clipping Help Layer - Light copy");
    var clippingHelpLayerLighter = doc.activeLayer;

    clippingHelpLayerLighter.name = "Clipping Help Layer - Lighter";
    clippingHelpLayerLighter.visible = false;

or maybe even like this :

    var clippingHelpLayerLighter = doc.artLayers.getByName("Clipping Help Layer - Light copy");

But I don't know why, the getByName doesn't work, saying it doesn't find the layer named like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem you are encountering has to do with `doc.activeLayer`. After you duplicate "Clipping Help Layer - Light," the script does not seem to change what `doc.activeLayer` is pointing to so when you then try to assign it to `clippingHelpLayerLighter`, you are then pointing at an undefined layer. While I don't know exactly what is happening behind the scenes when you do that, I do believe this will fix your problem:

```
#target photoshop

app.bringToFront();

var doc = app.documents.add( 4, 4 );

doc = app.activeDocument;

var clippingHelpLayerLight = doc.activeLayer;
clippingHelpLayerLight.blendMode = BlendMode.SCREEN;
clippingHelpLayerLight.name = "Clipping Help Layer - Light";
clippingHelpLayerLight.visible = false;
clippingHelpLayerLight.duplicate();

doc.activeLayer = doc.layers[ "Clipping Help Layer - Light copy" ];
doc.activeLayer.name = "Clipping Help Layer - Lighter";
doc.activeLayer.visible = false;

//I am not sure if you need this pointer to be called upon later in your 
//code. If you do not, just leave this line out.
var clippingHelpLayerLighter = doc.activeLayer;
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions, I'm by no means an expert but I use scripts fairly often.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It was indeed a problem of doc.activeLayer not pointing to the right thing. Your solution works fine, thank you !

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped.